# Código sempre cai no mesmo if

Tags: java, if, condição

Por que o método `souVelho()` só retorna a resposta "Você é novo.", independente da idade digitada? O que está dando errado?

```
public class Pessoa{
private int idade;  

public Pessoa(int idadeInicial) {
    if(idadeInicial<0){
        idade = 0;
        System.out.println("Idade invalida, idade determinada para 0.");
    }else{
        idadeInicial= idade;
    }
}

public void souVelho() {
    if(idade>=0 && idade<=12){
        System.out.println("Você é novo.");
    }
    else if(idade>=13 && idade<=17){
        System.out.println("Você é adolescente.");
    }
    else if(idade>=18){
        System.out.println("Você é velho.");
    }

}





    public void fazAniversario() {
        idade++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

O problema é a linha do construtor que está atribuindo o atributo da classe para a variável do construtor quando deveria ser o oposto.

O `this` neste caso de nada tem serventia já que ele não há conflito de nomes, eles já pegaria a propriedade da classe de qualquer forma.

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pessoa pessoa = new Pessoa(10);
        pessoa.souVelho();
        Pessoa pessoa2 = new Pessoa(15);
        pessoa2.souVelho();
        Pessoa pessoa3 = new Pessoa(20);
        pessoa3.souVelho();
        Pessoa pessoa4 = new Pessoa(-1);
        pessoa4.souVelho();
    }
}

class Pessoa {
    private int idade;  
    public Pessoa(int idadeInicial) {
        if (idadeInicial < 0) {
            idade = 0;
            System.out.println("Idade invalida, idade determinada para 0.");
        } else {
            idade = idadeInicial;
        }
    }
    public void souVelho() {
        System.out.println(idade);
        if (idade >= 0 && idade <= 12) System.out.println("Você é novo.");
        else if (idade >= 13 && idade <= 17) System.out.println("Você é adolescente.");
        else if (idade >= 18) System.out.println("Você é velho.");
    }
    public void fazAniversario() {
        idade++;
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/Z5pc7f). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/ikecycqp-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Algorithm/Age.java).

Answer (score 0):

Depois que me dei conta que eu escrevi `idadeInicial= idade;` quando deveria ser

```
idade = idadeInicial;
```

Acabei invertendo sem perceber, e me quebrando achando que tinha algo errado nos if.

Comment: É, eu acabei respondendo já que a resposta aceita não resolve de fato o problema e queria deixar isso claro, fica ruim as pessoas acharem que foi aquilo que resolveu.

Comment: Acho justo o `autor` retirar a aceitação, e colocar na correta.